# Program Run on DosBox Doesn't Generate Output Files

Tags: 64-bit, dosbox, assembly

I'm using windows 8.1 , 64 bit version , and I have a 16 bit assembler program which I'm trying to run using DosBox.
The program doesn't seem to generate output files , despite being called properly with valid parameters .

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Could have something to do with how your assembly program generates its output. For example whether it uses BIOS or DOS calls. Switching from one to the other might fix things.

Comment: DOSBox is not an x86 emulator, it's a DOS emulator, so certain (x86) assembly calls may just not work at all.

Comment: Actually it was recommended by the course faculty. I'm guessing that since the assembler was written by them ,then it must be a configuration problem on my side.

Comment: DosBox isn't perfect. Although it emulates a near fully-working DOS installation, it doesn't emulate certain things, that the dev team has no or little demand to develop. To check if the x64-86 paradigm isn't the problem, if you have access to a 32-bit OS, can you see if in it DosBox can do what you want?

Comment: Executing the same command on Windows 7 32 bit resulted in the error "This program cannot be run in DOS mode" , whereas on Windows 8.1 64 bit it did nothing as far as I can tell .I hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score -2):

> windows 8.1 , 64 bit version , and I have a 16 bit assembler program ...

That really says it all.

Windows Vista through Windows 8.1 x64 cannot run 16 bit applications. Windows on Windows can emulate a 32bit environment, but going back to 16 or 8 bit programs is not supported.

Comment: I explicitly specified that I'm using an emulator .